# Firebase Push Notification iOS issue, Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement Firebase Push Notifications for iOS, getting this msg : **Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"**

I'm using `Swift 2.3`, `Xcode 8`.

I have already set the APNs SSL Certificates in the Firebase Console, also have enable the Push Notification in Xcode App > Capabilities and check marked the Remote Notification option in BackgroundMode.
Also added `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = No` in `Info.plist` and the correct `Bundle ID` in `GoogleService-Info.plist`

One weird thing is happening that if I don't Enable the the Push Notification in Xcode App > Capabilities, I don't get the error, it prints the User Info and the Token :(
Kindly help.

Below is my *AppDelegate* code and the Output

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //for Firebase
       // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(
            authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // [END register_for_notifications]

    FIRApp.configure()

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                     selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                     name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification,
                                                     object: nil)

    return true
}


// [START receive_message]
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("message comes here")
    //print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
    print("message comes here end")

}
// [END receive_message]

// [START refresh_token]
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    connectToFcm()
}

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}


func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

   // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification,
                                                       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
       // Print message ID.
     //   print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
   // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
   func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}

// [END ios_10_message_handling]


--------OUTPUT
2016-10-20 15:50:03.051 ProgrammingHub[2747:916824] WARNING: Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.

2016-10-20 15:50:04.073 ProgrammingHub[2747:916824] [Crashlytics] Version 3.7.2 (112)

2016-10-20 15:50:04.287 ProgrammingHub[2747] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.

2016-10-20 15:50:04.314: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"

2016-10-20 15:50:04.326: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.2.0

2016-10-20 15:50:04.380 ProgrammingHub[2747:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3404000 started

2016-10-20 15:50:04.382 ProgrammingHub[2747:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http:/goo.gl/Y0Yjwu)

2016-10-20 15:50:04.692 ProgrammingHub[2747:916824] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.11 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002

2016-10-20 15:50:04.988 ProgrammingHub[2747:916824] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.11 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002

2016-10-20 15:50:05.208 ProgrammingHub[2747:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled

2016-10-20 15:50:05.391 ProgrammingHub[2747:916926] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.11 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher hitsForDispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:368): No pending hits.
2016-10-20 15:50:06.166 ProgrammingHub[2747] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Where are you having the problem?

Comment: I get this error msg  Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)" 
but if I print the token in this method . it gets printed./// also application(didRegisterUserNotificationSettings) is getting called before FCM connect so now I'm not able to subscribe the Topic as well

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Firebase/Core to v3.4.4, it fixed unexpected errors for me. Also, avoid calling `unregisterForRemoteNotifications`. After this call, you can't register the device anymore to push notifications.